# Cannot install Magento Magento-CE-2.0.5 on Cpanel due to always_populate_raw_post_data

Tags: magento2, installation

I got this error during installation:

[image]

I tried to change that value to -1 in php.ini/.htaccess .. without any result .. I didnt restart apache even whole OS.

here is my phpinfo:

[image]

[image]

@ /home/cconcept/public_html/php.ini:

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

Any hint how to fix it? it looks like a bug for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution thats working for me to change the php.ini @ /usr/local/lib/php.ini for whole server(VPS) which is not good .. since it may have impact on other accounts.

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = On
```

to

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

Im still looking for better solution ..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change php.ini file then I have another solution for you. You can change the value by adding two lines in .htaccess file in Magento 2 root folder. You have to add them under `<IfModule mod_php5.c>` in .htaccess file. The two lines are:

```
php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
php_value xdebug.max_nesting_level 200
```

See the screenshot below:

[image]

I hope this would help you.